# Interpolate array of SVG-Paths in svelte with d3.interpolateString

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte

I want to use the `tweened`-store from svelte in combinatin with the `interpolateString`-function from d3. As in here: https://svelte.dev/repl/2e753fbb33514bb8b8f4c928cbb39c6c?version=4.2.0

However, I want to animate 5 svg-lines. I have two arrays of length 5 with svg-path definitions. When the user clicks on a button, I want to interpolate the path of the first element in the first array to the first element in the second array and so on...

To my knowledge I can't create a top-level array of tweened-stores in svelte. So I thought I'd put each store in its own component which looks like this:

```
<script>
  import { tweened } from "svelte/motion";
  import { interpolateString } from "d3-interpolate";

  export let v;
  export let animated_path = tweened(null, {
    interpolate: interpolateString,
    duration: 1000,
  });

  $: animated_path.set(v);
</script>

<path d={$animated_path} fill="none" stroke="black" />
```

However, the paths update and show the new image. But they do not interpolate. Why is that?

Comment: Do the whole thing in SMIL or CSS animations then.

Comment: Thanks a lot!:) Sounds good, but I am not very confident and the svgs are rather complex paths. I really wonder what I am missing here...